# Can we get the details of every email ID in a list?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Suppose there's a List A, which has 10,000 Email Id's in it.
I want to generate a report where I get the following detail of every Email ID (10,000 in this case):

- **Sent Status**, which shows whether the email was sent or not
- **Open Status**, which shows whether the email has been opened or not
- **Click Status**, which shows whether the customer has clicked any link or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using query activity, we will make use of the data views _Sent, _Click, _Open. So if the email was sent to a subscriber it will be recorded in the sent view, opens and clicks will be recorded in the respective data views and we can retrieve up to 6 months of data from these. Sample queries look like this: ( you can find the ListID under properties tab of your list)

For Sent history:
select L.Subscriberkey,s.JobID,L.ListID
from _Sent s 
inner join _ListSubscribers L
on L.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
where ListID = 'your list ID'

For Clicks:
select L.Subscriberkey,C.JobID,L.ListID
from _Click C 
inner join _ListSubscribers L
on L.SubscriberKey = C.SubscriberKey
where ListID = 'your list ID'

For Opens:
select L.Subscriberkey,O.JobID,L.ListID
from _Open O 
inner join _ListSubscribers L
on L.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
where ListID = 'your list ID'

For more details on query activity and data views check here:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/